# Neutrino scattering cross-section in high energy limit

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section

I've come across a problem in out particle physics lecture notes that I have been unable to resolve on my own. I've paraphrased the bits of the notes that are giving me so much trouble:

The notes look at the following scattering problem:

[image]

They start off by saying that due to the W-boson exchange particle we have to insert a propagator into our matrix element, given by:

$$\frac{1}{q^2+m_w^2c^2}$$

with q beign the momentum of the W-boson.
In the high energy limit ($q \gg m_w^2c^2$) we can then approximate this propagator as

$$\frac{1}{q^2+m_w^2c^2} \approx \frac{1}{q^2}$$

and therefore get a matrix element given by:

$$M = \frac{\hbar^3cg_w^2}{q^2}$$

The density of states is given by:

$$\frac{dN}{dE} = \frac{4\pi V}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}{p_e}^2\frac{dp_e}{dE}$$

Again as we are in the high energy limit we can ignore all the rest mass energies involved such that

$$\frac{\sqrt{s}}{2} = E_\nu = E_e = p_e c \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ \sqrt{s} = E = \text{Center of mass Energy}$$

giving:

$$\frac{dN}{dE} = \frac{4\pi V}{8(2\pi\hbar c)^3}$$

Putting this all together into Fermis Golden Rule and converting $g_w$ to $G_F$ (which just groups together some of the constants) gives:

$$\sigma = \frac{4s}{q^4}\frac{G_F^2m_w^4}{\pi\hbar^4}$$

According to the notes then, because $$s = E_w^2 = \frac{q^4}{4m_w^2}$$ the cross section will actually be constant in this high energy limit.

There's two bits to this specifically that I've been unable to make sense of. Firstly the propagator: $$\frac{1}{q^2+m_w^2c^2}$$
The propagator is usually given as: $$\frac{1}{P_\mu P^{\mu}-m_w^2c^2}$$
What has happened to the energy term of $P_\mu P^{\mu}$? Why do we simply ignore it here to get to the propagator used in the notes?

Secondly where does the following line come from: $$s = E_w^2 = \frac{q^4}{4m_w^2}$$
I've been compeletly baffled by this and have spent hours trying to get to this result or justify it but have failed miserably. To me it seems that for the decay  geometry above we would get $P_\mu P^{\mu} = t$ with the t Mandelstram variable, such that the propagator will then be $\sim \frac{1}{t^2}$ with a final crosssection $\sigma \sim \frac{s}{t^2}$

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your subscripts for the outgoing lepton bespeak electron, but your diagram indicates μ. You start out with a space like metric and segue to a timeline one. Why don't you define carefully ***all*** your variables and what they mean? Your plea looks incoherent since your definitions are largely inconsistent. Try standard   [PDG notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473428/neutrino-scattering-cross-section-in-high-energy-limit).